# Dynamically check checkboxes for ng-show

Tags: angularjs, html

I know how to do this with ng-repeat. 
But I can't  find a solution for this way.

I have 6 checkboxes, and when I check any of them they show (ng-show) one of 6 charts.

The problem is my backend sends me array for pre-checked checkboxes in this way with API.

```
graphs_config:"["graph.batteryVoltage","graph.internetUserCount","graph.usbAndWirelessCharging"]"
```

I get this with `$promise` and check if there is data for pre-checked charts

```
$scope.charts= userChartsFactory.get({ user: user_id });
   $scope.charts.$promise.then(function(data) {
   if (data.graphs_config.indexOf("graph.batteryVoltage") >= 0) {
                $scope.graphBatteryVoltage = true;
            }
            if (data.graphs_config.indexOf("graph.internetUserCount") >= 0) {
                $scope.graphInternetUserCount = true;
            }
            if (data.graphs_config.indexOf("graph.usbAndWirelessCharging") >= 0) {
                $scope.graphUsbAndWirelessCharging = true;
            }
});
```

And in HTML I make this

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.batteryVoltage" value="battery_voltage" checklist-model="graph.graphBatteryVoltage" ng-checked="graph.graphBatteryVoltage" ng-model="graph.batteryVoltage" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(graph.batteryVoltage, 'graph.batteryVoltage')"><label for="graph.batteryVoltage">{{'BATTERY_VOLTAGE' | translate}}</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.internetUserCount" value="internet_user_count" checklist-model="graph.graphInternetUserCount" ng-checked="graph.graphInternetUserCount" ng-model="graph.internetUserCount" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(graph.internetUserCount, 'graph.internetUserCount')"><label for="graph.internetUserCount">{{'INTERNET_USER_COUNT' | translate}}</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.usbAndWirelessCharging" value="usb_and_wireless_charging" checklist-model="graph.usbAndWirelessCharging" ng-model="graph.usbAndWirelessCharging" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(graph.usbAndWirelessCharging, 'graph.usbAndWirelessCharging')"><label for="graph.usbAndWirelessCharging">{{'CHARGING_COUNTER' | translate}}</label>
</div>
```

I check if value is true or false and with `ng-checked` I try to CHECK checkboxes in HTML but this not working, because checkboxes are not pre-checked in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this working code.

Here Controller Code

```
$scope.data={
    FirstCheckbox:true,
    SecondCheckbox: false
    }
```

Here is HTML

```
  <label class="">
                <li class="item item-checkbox checkbox-dark " >
                    Test1
                       <label class="checkbox" >
                       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.FirstCheckbox" >
                       </label>
                    </li>
            </label>
    <label class="">
                <li class="item item-checkbox checkbox-dark " >
                    Test2
                       <label class="checkbox" >
                       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.SecondCheckbox" >
                       </label>
                    </li>
            </label>
```